# Will this design charge my batteries or burn them?

Tags: usb, battery-charging

I have designed the following circuit to charge my [Li-Po batteries](https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/detail/us-electronics-inc/USE-18650-3500MAH/15781477) while in circuit.

[image: Circuit Schematic]

Note that VIN is expected to pull a current as high as 2A when the board is running. Here's an explanation of what each component does:

J1 is a micro-B USB connector for charging.

U1 is a USB controller informing the connected device that its charging.

U3 and U4 are [MAX1811 chips](https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/detail/analog-devices-inc-maxim-integrated/MAX1811ESA/1513383) used to take the 5V USB and supply 4.2V to charge the Li-Po batteries.

Q1-4 are used as switches such that when EN is high, the batteries are no longer in series and disconnected from the remainder of the PCB (not shown), and when EN is low vice versa.

SW1 is just a button switch to turn the device on and off.

I used EN instead of CHGn for controlling the switches to avoid a short in case there is a delay between BATT and CHGn.

Would this work? Is there a fire-hazard risk?
Are the capacitors connected this way fine or is it problematic? And how should I choose the values for the capacitors?

Comment: What voltage is EN? If 0-3.3 V then Q3 will always be on, save for high Vgsth.

Comment: Well what i thought was gonna happen was if usb is connected then its 5V and if usb isnt connected then its pulled down to ground

Comment: Do you see how the battery voltage will affect the function of Q3?

Answer (score 2):

> Would this work? Is there a fire-hazard risk?

1. When not powered by USB the cells are connected in series, having a total voltage of up to 8.4 V. The MAX1811 is rated for an absolute maximum of 7 V between BATT and GND. So U3 will probably blow up.
2. When USB power is going down there will be a period when both Q2 and Q3 are on, shorting out the lower cell. Depending on Gate thresholds (which should not be relied on to prevent this 'shoot-through') the current could be very high. You may think it would only happen for a short time period, but if the USB power supply has high capacitance the voltage could go down very slowly. This could blow up the lower cell and/or the FETs.

So no, it won't work - and yes, there is a fire hazard.

> Are the capacitors connected this way fine or is it problematic? And
> how should I choose the values for the capacitors?

The capacitors are fine. The MAX1811 specifies a minimum of 2.2 μF across the battery, and 4.7 μF across the power input.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I see what you mean. Could you suggest another way to usb charge the 2-cell battery while in circuit? Another nmos added to the BATT of U3 would fix issue #1, but i cant think of something for issue #2.

Comment: Boost convertor from 5V to 7.4-8.4V.